# What's the input power of a switching controller?

Tags: power, switching-regulator

I'm looking at an Infineon [IR11662STRPBF](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-Technologies/IR11662STRPBF?qs=2r01AXMCG3N2d74aFi1TKg%3D%3D), which is listed as a "switching controller", but I think I've heard elsewhere that it's called a voltage rectifier, or maybe a voltage booster? The name of the thing is only a sidequest. My main question is this:

The thing has an output voltage and current. In other words it has an output power. Since it's not making power from nothing it must have an input power that's greater than the output power (to account for some resistance in the thing.) It has an input voltage, but I can't see any input current. Do I infer the input current from the input voltage and power? What happens if the input power is lower than the output power? What happens if the input power is much higher than the output power?

I would have assumed, before reading the specifications (most of which went right over my head,) that increasing the input current (and by implication the input power,) would have just changed the output current (and power.) Apparently it's a constant output of 1 ampere, no matter what, while also having an output voltage of 200 volts.

It says it has an "operating supply current" of 50 milliamps, but also a maximum input voltage of 20V. That's 1 watt. I don't think it's actually outputing 1 ampere at 200 volts from 1 watt, so what gives?

Answer (score 1):

The device in question, along with a MOSFET, replaces a lossy diode in the rectification of the secondary of a flyback converter (aka synchronous rectification): -

[image]

Image from the data sheet supplied in the question.

> *The thing has a output voltage and current. In other words it has an
> output power.*

Not really, it takes what power it needs from the secondary of the flyback transformer (XFM) and drives a MOSFET such that it creates an ideal-diode rectifier (rather than a regular lossy diode).

> *It says it has an "operating supply current" of 50 milliamps. But also
> a max input voltage of 20v. That's 1 watt. I don't think it's actually
> outputting 1 amp at 200 volts from 1 watt, so what gives?*

They are just the specifications for the chip; it doesn't output power to the load; it takes a little bit of power and drives the MOSFET (that does the real power rectification). If we didn't use the chip and MOSFET, the circuit would look like this: -

[image]

> *What's the input power of a switching controller?*

If the controller is driving a fairly high power MOSFET (\$C_{LOAD} = 10 \text{ nF}\$) at 400 kHz, it will take typically 50 mA. If the DC supply is 15 volts then, that's an input power of 750 mW and most of it will be dissipated driving the MOSFET's gate. However, this is at the limit of the device and, it may overheat (causing shutdown) if not using thick copper to the pins. The data sheet is a little vague about this but, given that it states the thermal resistance is 128 °C/watt, it may not take long to shutdown if appropriate thermal design steps are not taken.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this answer will be very useful to someone. But not me. I don't know what a MOSFET is, or "the rectification of the secondary of a flyback converter". Sounds like I'm just in way over my head. I thought this thing just upped the voltage by decreasing current, and I wanted to leave the rest as a black box that I didn't care to understand. But I guess that's not the case, and I'll have to understand what the heck is going on. But it is good to know the operating supply current is not going to the load (that much I understood from your answer).

Comment: Probably, @JosephSummerhays you need to study power supplies a bit more. Eventually you'll get to switching power supplies and, within that umbrella is the flyback converter but, it could take nearly a year of hard effort and sweat to get to that point. However, if it's of any use, this type of circuit (flyback converter) makes a very nice little capacitor charging power supply!!

Comment: If you don't know what a MOSFET is then yes, you're a fair ways away from understanding how this chip works in it's intended role.  However, I _was_ going to give you a "+1" for understanding that power out must equal power in -- now I'm giving you a "+100".

Comment: If it's not clear from what Andy said, the chip needs to get power to operate, and that's the power that's mentioned on the chip datasheet.  The chip is steering the MOSFET, and the MOSFET is steering the power in the supply -- **how much** power the MOSFET is steering depends on the details of the overall power supply design, and can be huge compared to the power consumption of the chip.

Comment: @TimWescott, how much power the MOSFET is steering is exactly the answer I want to know (or rather how much *can* it steer). I thought an output current and voltage implied an output power, but Andy said "not really", for reasons I'm probably months away from understanding (if I didn't have a job and family; probably years in reality). I guess the big take away for me is, this is a project where I can't wear all the hats, and I need a partner.

Comment: "How much power can the MOSFET steer?" is an answer that depends on multiple different factors, and pretty much requires someone who understands switching power theory to answer.  Then if you ask "but will the circuit blow up?" you need someone with theoretical knowledge _and_ experience in design.